# How to convert CvMat* to cv::Mat in OpenCV3.0

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

In opencv2.4.10 which I used before, conversion from CvMat* to cv::Mat can be done as below.

```
CvMat *src = ...;
cv::Mat dst;
dst = cv::Mat(src);
```

However, in opencv3.0 rc1 cannot convert like this.
In certain website, this conversion can be done as below.

```
CvMat* src = ...;
cv::Mat dst;
dst = cv::Mat(src->rows, src->cols, src->type, src->data.*);
```

If type of src is 'float', the last argument is 'src->data.fl'.

Why constructor of cv::Mat is decreased?
Or are there some methods about conversion from CvMat* to cv::Mat?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CvMat* matrix;
Mat M0 = cvarrToMat(matrix);
```

OpenCV provided this function instead of Mat(matrix).

Note: In OpenCV 3.0 they wrapped up all the constructors which convert old-style structures (cvmat, IPLImage) to the new-style Mat into this function.

Comment: The note is very helpful, I just edited it to stand a bit more out now.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert `CvMat*` to `Mat` you have to do like this:

```
cv::Mat dst(src->rows, src->cols, CV_64FC1, src->data.fl);
```